# Google container engine

Tags: kubernetes

I created the kubernetes cluster and i am not able to connect to the cluster, getting below error.

rakesh_pal@sandbox:~$ gcloud beta container clusters get-credentials map-c1 --region us-central1 --project sandboxWarning: you invoked `gcloud beta`, but with current configurationKubernetes Engine v1 API will be used instead of v1beta1 API.If you intended to use v1beta1 API instead, please setcontainer/use_v1_api_client property to false.Do you want to continue (Y/n)? YFetching cluster endpoint and auth data.ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=400, message='us-central1' is not a valid zone.rakesh_pal@sandbox:~$

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

I succeeded after using this command:

gcloud config set container/use_v1_api false

Comment: Thank you so much. After i ran gcloud config set container/use_v1_api_client false. it worked for and no more error. but when I ran kubectl proxy, its just keep hanging on Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001

Answer (score 0):

try without the beta and the region info in the command, your instructions might be old.  container engine is not in beta anymore.

make sure your gcloud cli is current with

```
gcloud components update
```

then

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials dev-map-c1 (created new cluster and same issue i have)
```

EDIT

In case your default config zone is not the one you want to use, you can explicitly specify it on the commands.  The commands below work for me:

create cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters create dev-map-c1 --zone us-east1-b --machine-type=custom-1-4096 --cluster-version=1.8.4-gke.1
```

get config:

```
gcloud container clusters --zone=us-east1-b get-credentials dev-map-c1
```

Comment: I am still getting same error.

rakesh_pal@sandbox:~$ gcloud components update
All components are up to date.
rakesh_pal@sandbox:~$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials dev-map-c1
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=404, message=The resource "projects/sandbox/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/dev-map-c1" was not found.
Could not find [dev-map-c1] in [us-central1-a].
Did you mean [dev-map-c1] in [us-central1]?

Comment: thx for trying it.  I just ran through the commands and it worked for me. I wonder if you created your cluster in one zone and your gcloud config is pointing to another?  that seems to be what the error messages are saying. check that your "gcloud config list" shows the same zone you created the cluster in.

Comment: Hmm. Same issue. 

Another data point:

All components updated.

gcloud config list:
[compute]
region = us-east1
zone = us-east1-b

$ gcloud beta container clusters create $CLUSTER \
--cluster-version=1.8.4-gke.1 \
--machine-type=custom-1-4096 \
--region=$REGION \
--project=$PROJECT
$ echo $CLUSTER $REGION
jdar-171227-cluster-01 us-east1

Comment: good news, I think I reproduced the issue. I was able to get the same error message by having the cluster in a different zone than my default.  I'll post the cluster create command and get-credentials commands that worked for me in my answer above.

Comment: another thing is, i have to run the command everytime when i am login to clueter. gcloud config set container/use_v1_api_client false
is there any permananet solution for this?.

Comment: if you don't use the "beta" in the create you don't need the use_v1_api_client=false.  I just use the commands above (see my updated answer) and I end up with a perfectly healthy cluster.  Or at least that's how it works for me.  I'd be careful to make sure you are consistent with "zone" and are not using "beta".